# Matlab to C# bitmap image passing

Tags: c#, image, matlab, rgb, figure

I have an algorithm implemented in Matlab and deployed as a .DLL

My C# code calls the functions from the .DLL and as a result of this data is generated for building a plot. I would like to have the matlab code create a RGB image out of this plot and send the raw bytes of that image to C#.

Could anyone please post some code which does just that?

I am currently building the plot using

```
$h = figure('visible', 'off');
plot(mydata);
print(h, '-r80', '-dbmp', file1);
```

which I find a bit inefficient (am I wrong, perhaps?) because of the disk I/O operation. I would rather convert this to raw RGB data and pass the resulting matrix to C#. I have no idea how to do this. I have tried using ind2rgb on a dummy image like this: ind2rgb(spiral(5), colormap) but this doesn't seem to provide integer RGB values. They still seem indexed in the local colormap. Also I have no idea how to use the ind2rgb function on a figure data (I don't know how to obtain the image data of a figure object).

So if someone would be so kind as to provide me with a method to get the raw image bytes (only the pixel data, no header) associated with the figure and convert it to RGB. I know how to pass this back to C#.

Thanks!

Comment: What's to stop you from returning the bytes that represent the image in your function and saving into c# structures?

Comment: I am new to Matlab and I have no idea on how to do this. I've looked it up and was unable to reach the right places to find this information so to speak. As I'm pointing up above I know there is a function ind2rgb which converts indexed colors to RGB, but I don't know how to access the actual image data of the figure object.

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB open deploytool() and create a .net assembly, then link to the dll in your program. When you call the function do something like this:

```
AssemblyName.ClassName myClass = new AssemblyName.ClassName();
MWArray results = myClass.FunctionName(...functionArgs);
```

Your results array will have the array that your MATLAB function returned. Just make sure that your MATLAB function returns the byte values of the pixels. You can get the dimensions of the `results MWArray` by calling :

```
int[] dim = results.Dimensions;
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing RGB data of printed plot will not look well in your C# application. That is because you raster your vector graphics to specific size, and resizing it looks ugly.

Instead I recommend using vector graphics. Pass the plot in its abstract form `(X,Y)` and maybe other properties like `color`. If it is more complicated, write an interface to pass that information.

Make the C# application draw the plot by writing a native function that calls [chart controls](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14422).

Answer (score 0):

The wording might no have been appropriate in my original question but I was looking for something like this:

```
h = figure('visible', 'off');
plot(mydata);
F = getframe(h);
im = F.cdata;
```